# compare observable arrays with different elements

Tags: knockout.js

I wish to compare 2 observable arrays. I have defined 2 observable arrays as below

```
var data1 = [{name1: "one"}, {name1: "two"}, {name1: "three"}];
var data2 = [{name2: "one"}, {name2: "two"}, {name2: "three"}];

dataOne: ko.observableArray(data1),
dataTwo: ko.observableArray(data2)
```

You can see data1 has different element name than data2. I wish to compare 2 observable arrays and return data matching with each other. So in our case it will be "two" and "three"

After doing this i will bind this to checkbox which will set checkbox to checkbox with matching data. I have put up fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3ru/15/)

I want to bind the checkbox with value from observable array dataTwo. How to achieve this?

Forgot to mention that in my fiddle i have just one checkbox but in my actual scenario it will be multiple checkboxes which will be binded to the data.

---

I have now updated fiddle. You can see that i am binding checkbox to dataOne but want to be checked based on element in datatwo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got to admit, I'm still rather confused as to what you are trying to achieve here. I suggest that you pre-process the two arrays to produce a single array containing the values that are in both arrays. Then, when you are looping over each array, you can see if the current value is in the list of duplicates and check the box if it is.

First, add an observable array to your viewModel:

```
duplicates: ko.observableArray()
```

You can flatten each of your arrays using:

```
var flattenedOne = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.dataOne(), function(item) {
    return item.name1;
});
flattenedOne = flattenedOne.sort();

var flattenedTwo = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.dataTwo(), function(item) {
    return item.name2;
});
flattenedTwo = flattenedTwo.sort();
```

Then use compare to get the ones that are in both arrays:

```
var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(viewModel.flattenedOne, viewModel.flattenedTwo);
//return a flat list of differences
ko.utils.arrayForEach(differences, function(difference) {
    if (difference.status === 'retained') {
        viewModel.duplicates.push(difference.value);
    }
});
```

Then you data-bind using:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1" />
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3ru/42/).

Comment: I am sorry if i caused confusion. I have updated fiddle once more as per your code http://jsfiddle.net/Jq3ru/35/
What i want is that my checkboxes will be bind to "dataOne" but it will be checked depending upon matching values with "dataTwo" I still cant get it to checked. In our case now 2 checkboxes will be checked as only two data are matching i.e "two" and "three". Hope its clear now.

Comment: I did put a fiddle together with this last night, and it did work. It was on my home pc though, so I can't post it here. I'll take a look at your update soon.

Comment: Hey this is what i need. But just one query. Is it possible to bind checkbox with data from "dataTwo" observable array? You have binded it like $root.duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1, so can we do it like $root.duplicates.indexOf(name2) !== -1 ?

Comment: Also would like to know what is duplicates.indexOf(name1) !== -1? I didnt understood it quite.

Comment: Duplicates contains the data values that are in both dataOne and dataTwo. The checkboxes are bound to dataOne, and the checked function is just seeing if the name1 from dataOne is in duplicates, as this means that the value is also in dataTwo. Does that make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26446/discussion-between-ashreva-and-paul-manzotti)

Comment: Perfecto :). Very nice. All the best luck in your life.